# Calculate average tuples in one million dataset scenario

Tags: python

Given a dataset of one million data, I wish to calculate the average price of items. Some of the itemID are replicated, and that's the key.

For instance, given the following dictionary:

```
res = {
   '155': ['3','4','5'],
   '222': ['1'],
   '345': ['6','8','10']
   .
   (+ 1 million more lines) 
   .}
```

I wish to calculate the average price for each itemID and return a dictionary. Expected output will be:

```
{'155': ['4'], 
'222': ['1'], 
'345': ['8']
.
.
.}
```

, where the integer next to itemid is the average price.

I wish to unpack the `res` list and calculate the average price before returning the result as a dictionary.

```
for x, y in res:
// calculate average and add into new dictionary
```

However, the terminal shows that there is a problem:

```
----> 9     for k, l in res:
 10         print(k)
 11 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Am i supposed to iterate through 1 million datasets to get the average price? Any help will be great!

Comment: `(6+8+10)/3` is 8. Can you explain `345: 10`?

Comment: And are you sure you're getting that particular `ValueError`? I only get that if I change those integer keys to strings.

Comment: This does not indeed raise a `ValueError`. Edit your question and supply the dictionary *as you used it in your code*. Ambiguity doesn't help anyone.

Comment: The dict keys are probably strings longer than 2 characters: `>>> for k,v in {'abc': 1}:` raises the same exception: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: hi gents, i am so sorry for the ambiguity. I made the edits as requested, hope it will help someone in future. Thanks all who helped!

Comment: Why do you want an average to be stored as a string in a singleton `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__iter__` attribute of a dictionary object iterates over it's keys, therefore when you iterate over your dictionary you are iterating over the keys and you just need one throwaway variable.

If you want to iterate over keys and values you must iterate over items :

```
for key, value in res.items:
      # do stuff
```

And for your task you can use a dictionary comprehension to calculate the average of your prices:

```
{key:sum(value)/len(value) for key,value in res.items()}
```

*Note*: If you use python 2.X instead of `items()` use `iteritems()` which returns an iterator of items and is more optimized in terms of  memory use.

Also note that `(1)` is not a tuple and you need to convert it to `(1,)` in order to refuse of getting `ValueError` :

```
>>> res = {
...    155: (3,4,5),
...    222: (1,),
...    345: (6,8,10)}
>>> 
>>> {key:sum(value)/len(value) for key,value in res.items()}
{345: 8, 155: 4, 222: 1}
```

But if it's not possible to change that value you need to check the type of the value before calling the `len()` function of it:

```
{key:sum(value)/len(value) if isinstance(value,tuple) else value for key,value in res.items()}

>>> res = {
...    155: (3,4,5),
...    222: (1),
...    345: (6,8,10)}
>>> 
>>> {key:sum(value)/len(value) if isinstance(value,tuple) else value for key,value in res.items()}
{345: 8, 155: 4, 222: 1}
```

Comment: Thank you! you predicted what other problems i will face! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `iteritems`

```
for x, y in res.iteritems():
    // calculate average and add into new dictionary
```

If you do it like `for x, y in res:` then only keys are returned not values  hence the error, you are doing `x, y = key` so it will give error too many values to unpack. Whereas `iteritems()` returns `(key, value)` tuple so you need `iteritems()`. For python3 use `res.items()` instead of `res.iteritems()` which is for python2.

Comment: Note that the given error message does not match the given code.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 you are right. It should be `TypeError` for int objects. But may be OP instead of copying values from his original code put new values here. So he might have used strings in his original code, hence the `ValueError`. Can be cleared only by OP :).

Comment: Yes, i am working on company data and I've replaced the data with fake ones. Thanks a lot, you've helped a lot!